# Vue.js + SVG Map - how to style selected item?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, vuejs2, dom-events

I have SVG map and .selected class in my  which adds color to the selected province:

```
.selected {
  fill: brown;
}
```

I cannot add any methods or events to HTML directly, because I will use different maps.

I use an event listener in my methods to access data and render it based on the province that was clicked.

How can I do it with the .selected class? So if I click the given province it get a .selected class and if I click another one the previous one loses the .selected class?

Here is my snippet with my code: https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/marektchas/507954

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `.selected` class programmatically.

First add a new method to remove the class on all paths, then add the class for the selected element on click:

```js
methods: {

  removeSelection (paths) {
    paths.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("selected")) 
  },

  addClickHandler() {
    let paths = this.$el.querySelectorAll('path')
    paths.forEach(el => {
      let id = el.attributes.id.value
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.province = this.provinces.find(province => province.id == id)

        this.removeSelection(paths)
        el.classList.add("selected")

        // Animation
        this.isActive = true
        setTimeout(() => { this.isActive = false }, 200)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional class binding as described in the vue.js docs under [Class & Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

In your case, this could look like

```
<path d="...snip..."
   id="AL" name="Albania" :class="{selected: province.id == 'AL'}">
</path>
```

Since this would force you to add the comparison for each province, I'd suggest you render the SVG dynamically:

- Add the SVG path to the province's data, e.g. `{ id: 'LT', name: 'Lithuania', vat: 21, path='M707.9 ... 0.5z' }`
- Since [you can simply create SVG using vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/editable-svg-icons.html#Base-Example) you can render the provinces in a [loop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) and bind all it's properties, e.g.

  ```
    <path v-for="p in provinces" :key="p.id"
        :d="p.path"
        :id="p.id" 
        :name="p.name" 
        :class="{selected: province.id == p.id}">
  ```

Going this way would significantly shrink your markup.